# My prefix is a clue

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

An Affix Riddle:

- My prefix is a clue
- My infix is a stutter
- My suffix combines

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are

> hinterland

My prefix is a clue

> a hint is a clue

My infix is a stutter

> er can be taken as a pause or stutter

My suffix combines

> and is a conjunction

Comment: Just beat me to it! :D

Comment: That was really quick. I will accept this when I can (in 10 minutes.)